# Schengen tourist visa refusal

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, applications, finland

I have been refused a Schengen tourist visa reason being the information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.I don't understand because I provided a cover letter explaining my intention for the trip together with my itinerary.Someone kindly advise what I should do in case I decide to reapply.Thanks.

Comment: It is just one of the different options they use to deny applications. You will not get any much deeper explanation than what is provided unfortunately. You are being denied a lot of visas, from your previous questions. You may want to hit pause and reevaluate your applicant/immigration profile to see what you are doing wrong or if you even qualify for the visas at all.

Comment: It means, in short, that either they do not understand you or they do not believe you. Gayot Fow's answer to the question CMaster has linked contains useful information.